# Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 on computer with that system?

Tags: 14.04, system

Processor: AMD Duron-1.31ghz
RAM-640mb
Video card:GeForce MX 40-32MB
 Is Ubuntu 14.04 will run smoothly and better than Windows XP on this computer ?

Comment: Try to install Lubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu with less than 1.2 GB of RAM will be almost unusable.

Comment: You can write a LiveCD, boot from it and test how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try Puppy Linux.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppy_Linux

Puppy Linux operating system is a lightweight Linux distribution that focuses on ease of use and minimal memory footprint. The entire system can be run from RAM with current versions generally taking up about 210 MB, allowing the boot medium to be removed after the operating system has started.

Comment: Is LibreOffice included in PuppyLinux, because I use this computer for work and I need  LibreOffice

Comment: LibreOffice can be installed at any time.